# I saw a lakeside castle or hotel from the air, north of Newark. What is it?

Tags: identify-this, ewr, new-england, new-york-state

I recently flew into Newark on a transatlantic flight from Glasgow, UK. I happened to be looking out of the aircraft window (left side) during the descent, and saw a rather unique-looking scene:

A small lake, with a large castle or hotel-like building on the western shore, and some distinctive rocks or cliff faces (reminiscent of Mount Rushmore) on the eastern shore of the lake. The building and its location reminded me very much of the [Fairmont Lake Louise](http://www.fairmont.com/lake-louise/) hotel, although this one I think was much smaller.

According to the in-flight display, this was approximately 90 miles north-north-east of Newark. It could have been in New York State or one of the New England states. I have looked on Google Earth but haven't been able to find it.

Can you help me identify this very pretty-looking location?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My guess would be the [Mohonk Mountain House](http://www.mohonk.com/), "Around the last bend, a Victorian castle rises above Lake Mohonk, surrounded by carefully landscaped gardens and pristine wilderness. Inside you discover a warm interior that is reminiscent of the beauty outside – extensive woodwork, fireplaces constructed from Shawangunk stone, and expansive windows that frame the breathtaking scenery."

[image]

> "[Mohonk Mountain House 2011 Main Buildings around Lake 1 FRD 3077](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mohonk_Mountain_House_2011_Main_Buildings_around_Lake_1_FRD_3077.jpg#mediaviewer/File:Mohonk_Mountain_House_2011_Main_Buildings_around_Lake_1_FRD_3077.jpg)" by Fred Hsu on en.wikipedia - Own work. Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via [Wikimedia Commons](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

The whole area can be well viewed by [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Mohonk%20Lake,%20Ulster%20County,%20NY&hl=en&ll=41.765158,-74.155505&spn=0.006306,0.010622&sll=41.385712,-73.738539&sspn=0.012686,0.021243&oq=lake%20mohonk&t=h&hnear=Mohonk%20Lake&z=17)

Southeast of the lake is a talus mound, atop which sits the Albert K. Smiley memorial.

[image]

> "[Skytop Tower at Mohonk](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Skytop_Tower_at_Mohonk.jpg#mediaviewer/File:Skytop_Tower_at_Mohonk.jpg)" by Jarek Tuszynski aka [Jarekt](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Jarekt) - Own work. Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via [Wikimedia Commons](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

Another interesting view, available within Google Maps is the [Mohonk Labyrinth Trail](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mohonk+Mountain+House/@41.7634544,-74.1566925,3a,90y,131.77h,69.58t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1s1T3JPZNPjYgAAAQYW8gQoQ!2e0!3e11!4m2!3m1!1s0x89dd1f41bce35abd:0x339dbee1a4648163), providing a close us panorama of the talus rock falls.

Comment: I note they claim to be 90 miles from NYC: looking on the map that means they're the same distance from Newark. I'm convinced!

Comment: Sounds like a good match.  I hope the OP can confirm this is what he saw!

Comment: Yes, I believe this is it. Nice find!

Comment: This image gives a better perspective on the rock face which reminded me of Mount Rushmore: http://www.esri.com/news/arcnews/winter1112articles/winter1112gifs/p8p1-lg.jpg